# Why am I I not getting a list

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7

I have this json file

```
{
"children": [{
        "objName": "Sprite1",
        "scripts": [[69,
                57,
                [["whenGreenFlag"],
                    ["broadcast:", "Pin D On"],
                    ["wait:elapsed:from:", 3],
                    ["broadcast:", "Pin D Off"],
                    ["wait:elapsed:from:", 1]]]],
        "sounds": [{
                "soundName": "meow",
                "soundID": 0,
                "md5": "83c36d806dc92327b9e7049a565c6bff.wav",
                "sampleCount": 18688,
                "rate": 22050,
                "format": ""
            }]
    }]
```

}

that I'm trying to parse the GreenFlag information but when I run this

```
> import ast import json from pprint import pprint
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> codeInput = [] codeOutput = []
> 
> with open("project.json") as projectFile:
>     codeInput =json.load(projectFile)
> 
> print type(codeInput)
> 
> #pprint(codeInput)
> #print"----"
> 
> #print codeInput["children"]
> 
> scripts = codeInput["children"][0]["scripts"] print type(scripts) for
> items in scripts:
>     print "items",items
> 
> print scripts[2]
```

I'm not getting a list I'm getting this but it looks like it should be
a list to me

```
<type 'dict'>
<type 'list'>
items [69, 57, [[u'whenGreenFlag'], [u'broadcast:', u'Pin D On'], [u'wait:elapsed:from:', 3], [u'broadcast:', u'Pin D Off'], [u'wait:elapsed:from:', 1]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dropbox/Private/Scratch2Crumble/projectparser.py", line 46, in <module>
    print scripts[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am i doing wrong?

I've just added this extra text in order to try and get my questin posted

Comment: What's with having multiple commands on a single line? e.g. `codeInput = [] codeOutput = []`

Comment: @khelwood: Looks to me like the questioner hit the "quote" button before the "code" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value associated with the key `"scripts"` in your dictionary is a list with one element.

```
"scripts": [[69,
            57,
            [["whenGreenFlag"],
                ["broadcast:", "Pin D On"],
                ["wait:elapsed:from:", 3],
                ["broadcast:", "Pin D Off"],
                ["wait:elapsed:from:", 1]]]],
```

Where you have two open-brackets after `"scripts":`, this means that you have a list with one element, and that element is another list containing `69, 57` etc.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the value associated to `scripts` is a list containing a single element, which is a list.
You can see it when output is better formatted:

```
[
    [
        69,
        57,
        [
            ["whenGreenFlag"],
            ["broadcast:", "Pin D On"],
            ["wait:elapsed:from:", 3],
            ["broadcast:", "Pin D Off"],
            ["wait:elapsed:from:", 1]
        ]
    ]
]
```

So you'll have to call `scripts[0][2]` to get what you want.